# What are the allowed condition types in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, search-criteria

What is the list of allowed condition types while adding **filter** to **search criteria** in Magento 2?

All of the examples about search criteria in the internet use `eq` condition type. Is there any other? Do you have a complete list somewhere?

EDIT 1:
Please look at the following code block. What are my options for **condition_type**?

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository */
$productRepository = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::class);

/** @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder */
$searchCriteriaBuilder = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder::class);

/** @var \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder */
$filterBuilder = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder::class);
$filterSpecialPrice = $filterBuilder->setField('special_price')
    ->setValue('0')
    ->setConditionType('eq')
    ->create();

$searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($filterSpecialPrice)
    ->create();

$productCollection = $productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

available conditions

```
 "eq" => equalValue
 "neq" => notEqualValue
 "like" => likeValue
 "nlike" => notLikeValue
 "is" => isValue
 "in" => inValues
 "nin" => notInValues
 "notnull" => valueIsNotNull
 "null" => valueIsNull
 "moreq" => moreOrEqualValue
 "gt" => greaterValue
 "lt" => lessValue
 "gteq" => greaterOrEqualValue
 "lteq" => lessOrEqualValue
 "finset" => valueInSet
 "from" => fromValue, "to" => toValue
```

[Link to the docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/performing-searches.html)

Comment: Here is the official documentation about search criteria, which also displays the available conditions.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html

Comment: The Devdocs page in the comment above isn't valid anymore, check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html for the avaiable types.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one as well from the document

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html