# How to get product collection unmatch product ids with custom collection ids in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection, catalog-product

I want to get the unmatched product ids of catalog products with a custom module collection product ids.

For Example :

1. The catalog product entity table has 12,14,15,16 product ids
2. The custom table has 12,14 product ids.

**Result:** 15,16 -> Unmatched Product Ids.

How we can achieve this using Magento standard approach?

Comment: Use mysql inner join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **You can use not in the condition in addFieldToFilter() of your collection. Which magento provide.**

```
$arrayIds = [12,13];

$collection->addFieldToFilter('your_id_column', ['nin' => $arrayIds ]);
```

[For more conditions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184309/82670)